# Integer division: is a//b == int(a/b) true for all integers a,b?

Tags: python, python-3.x, integer-division

I know that integer division will always return the same answer as truncation of a floating point result if the numbers are both positive. Is it true if one or both of them are negative?

I was just curious to know if there was an integer division expression that would return the same results in Python 2 and Python 3 (and yes, I know about `from __future__ import division`).

P.S. Let's ignore floating point overflow for the moment.

Comment: *" an integer division expression that would return the same results in Python 2 and Python 3"* Come again?

Comment: @NullUserException, in Python 3 if you use `/` to divide two integers you will get a floating point result. This is a huge change from Python 2. `//` is now necessary to get the old behavior.

Comment: I still dont understand why they auto upcast to a float .... seems silly to me... I mean `int/int = int` is a core tenet of CS ...

Comment: I still don't get it. *"if there was an integer division expression that would return the same results in Python 2 and Python 3"* For any ints a,b such that a%b == 0, the results are the same.

Comment: @JoranBeasley Rationale here: http://docs.python.org/release/2.2.3/whatsnew/node7.html

Comment: @JoranBeasley: I don't know what their rationale is, but it seems clear to me that integer division and floating point division are different operators and should be treated as such. Having to cast one of the operands to double in C and C++ has always felt awkward and wrong to me.

Comment: thanks ... still think its strange ...

Comment: @NullUserException, thanks for the link. I didn't realize the `//` operator was added all the way back in 2.2.

Comment: @JoranBeasley: you really think that in a duck-typed language you shouldn't just be able to treat a number as a number and assume `/` does actual division just because C is statically typed? Integer division is hardly a "core tenet of CS".

Comment: @MarkRansom: What needs to be added to my answer to make it acceptable?

Comment: @Omnifarious absolutely nothing. I just make it a habit not to accept something right away. You got my +1 long ago. P.S. great answer.

Comment: @MarkRansom: Thanks! I thought it was something like that. I have the same habit. I just wanted to make sure I answered your question completely.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is not true in Python 3, and you can test it for yourself:

```python
>>> int(-1/3) == -1//3
False
```

Integer division and modulo of `a` and `b` giving `q` (quotient) and `r` (remainder) respectively will always return numbers that satisfy `b*q + r == a` and `(a*b)>0 == q>0` (i.e. `a*b` and `q` have the same sign) and `abs(r) < abs(q)`. The expression `int(q)` simply always rounds towards 0 if `q` is a floating point number.

It will always be true for Python 2 unless you do `from __future__ import division`, but that's because `a/b == a//b` if `a` and `b` are integers in Python 2.

Comment: `>>> int(-1/3) == -1//3`  ->`
True`  I got that they were true when I tried it in py26 ...

Comment: @JoranBeasley - That's because in Python 2.6 `a/b == a//b` if `a` and `b` are integers.

Comment: @JoranBeasley Because in Python 2, `/` with two integer operands does precisely what `//` does. We're talking about Python 3 (compatibility) here, and in Python 3 they differ.

Comment: yeah ok I understand now sorry :P

Comment: on a side note in 26 I get they are the same even if I do `from __future__ import division` ...

Comment: @JoranBeasley: Really? That's not the result I get with Python 2.6 or 2.7. In both of them `/` changes to always return a floating point number once you do `from __future__ import division`.

Comment: ahh your right ... I had a typo ... sorry :P thanks for the informative post :)